# Parallax image with gradient overlay

Tags: css

I am styling a call to action area which has a background image with the following html:

```
<section id="callout" class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url('images/image-1.jpg');">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

With the following css:

```
.jumbotron {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.3), rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.3));
    background: no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
```

I am trying to add a gradient overlay over the image which is not working. I know in css I could add one line with the background image url and linear gradient like below:

```
.jumbotron {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(20,20,20, .3), rgba(20,20,20, .3)), url("../images/image-1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    //background: no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
```

However I would like to keep the background image being loaded via the html (to change through CMS later) instead of css but change the linear-gradient from the style.css if possible.

I have tried using .jumbotron:after {} and adding the gradient that way but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A gradient is considered to be a background image. You are setting this on `.jumbotron`, and then overwriting it by way of inline style with a jpg.

To accomplish the effect you are trying for, set `.jumbotron` to `position: relative;`, set `.jumbotron > .container` to `position: relative; z-index: 2` and add an extra direct child to `.jumbotron` with the following (simplified) CSS:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
background: linear-gradient(rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.3), rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.3));
```

Comment: Thank you that worked and adding the direct child div containing the class with the linear-gradient css jogged my memory I actually did this same thing on a previous project.